# How can I install vmware tools?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, vmware

I run Ubuntu 16.04 on Vmware box version 12.5.2. Trying to install Vamware tools using these commands:

```
VM->Install vmware tools
copy whole VMWare Tools directory to ~
run sudo ./run_upgrade.sh
```

But nothing is happening and no error messages appear? How can I install vmware tools in the correct way?

Answer (score 11):

You should go to the console on the virtual machine while it is running and install the tools.

You can use 3rd-party vmware tools that are available in the Ubuntu repository (contrary to the VMware-provided packages that are not available in the main repo):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

For virtual machine that is a desktop installation you can also add some destkop-environment based tools:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

But for server installation you should definitely drop this out.

EDIT:
Actually, there is a comprehensive tutorial that answers your question.  I hope nobody decides to remove this plot due to this...
[VMware Tools community help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools)

Comment: This works nicely with VMWare Workstation Player 15 and Ubuntu Desktop